# Install newer .NET and run a child process that uses it from one parent process?

Tags: windows, testing, process, environment

I'm trying to automate some test runs in my company and constraint I operate under is that I have one process (that I can change to run whatever I want), but once it finishes automation cleans up machine.
I cannot change state of machine before this process starts.

Requirement for test is to install .NET 4.5 and then start another process that uses it.

Problem I'm facing is that second process cannot find some of .NET 4.5 dll's that get installed in one of the previous steps (I basically start installer process, it finishes and then I kick off tests).

If I remote desktop into that machine and start test process manually again it loads and works correctly.

So my quiestion is - is there any way to start test process as a child of "system" or can I make it reload environment somehow?

Comment: include the .net 4.5 dll's with your program?

Comment: Have you checked whether the install requires a system reboot?

Comment: I have tried copying DLLs into working directory and adding working dir into path, but it didn't help, for reboot - I cannot do it unfortunately.